# Generate column Alias name dynamically in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to Generate column Alias name dynamically in MS SQL Server, Please advise on the same. Thank you.

I need to out a value from sp with the alias name which is coming through one input parameter on the same sp.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. An alias is a temporary name in a query to reference a table or a column. What would you want the aliases to be?

Comment: Without comments it is hard to be sure, but I suspect this question has been downvoted for a lack of effort.  Generally speaking you are expected to have a go yourself and then post your code and error messages.  See this guide for [more](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi all, i need to out the value from sp with the alias name which is coming through one input parameter on the same sp.

Comment: Guys, seriously, the butchering here needs to stop. It has became a very unpleasant experience to ask questions in this site. and as for Ram's question - reading the topic was more than enough to understand his request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create procedure my_procedure (@col_alias varchar(100))
as
    declare @my_stmt nvarchar(max) = N'select 1+1 as ' + @col_alias
    exec sp_executesql @stmt = @my_stmt
```

---

```
exec my_procedure @col_alias = '[This is a dynamix col alias]'
```

---

```
This is a dynamix col alias
---------------------------
2
```

Comment: can you please provide a sample for the same, since it will be more helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ram, please check the edited answer

Comment: Thank you, But the same is not working in the below scenario, why?

Comment: @ram, what scenario?

Comment: declare col_alias varchar(100)
set col_alias = 'ggg'
declare my_stmt nvarchar(max) = N'select top 1 employee_code from epin_employee as ' + col_alias
exec sp_executesql stmt = my_stmt

Comment: @ram, parameter should start with **@**, e.g. **@col_alias**

Comment: I have added the scenario above, please check

Comment: in comments section it wont allow to add @ symbol in stackoverflow

Comment: @ram, this works: `declare @col_alias varchar(100) set @col_alias = 'ggg' declare @my_stmt nvarchar(max) = N'select 1+1 ' + @col_alias exec sp_executesql @stmt = @my_stmt`

Comment: @Ram, P.s. you can use formatting to avoid issues: **@** , `@` , "@"

Comment: @Ram, don't put the answer in the question :-)

Comment: N'select top 1 employee_code from epin_employee as ' + @col_alias, it wont works

Comment: Your code worked for me (but I've changed the query). What is the error message?

Comment: thanks a lot, it works for me, really appreciate for your great help,

Comment: you're welcomed :-) (P.s.,since the answer was correct, please mark it as such)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to dynamically generate the entire SQL statement, with the column aliases, and then use  [SQLExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713584(v=vs.85).aspx) `exec SQLExecute`.

Comment: Example please.

Comment: example is `exec SQL Execute [here put the sql statement you want to execute]`.    - read the link.